# Empty result when reading TOML file with Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to read a toml file with Go. I want to have different filesystems not only `filesystem.file` but for example also `filesystem.s3`, which have different paths defined. But it only returns an empty struct `{map[file:{map[]}]}`. What am I missing?

I'm using this library for reading the toml file: https://github.com/BurntSushi/toml

toml file:

```
[filesystem.file]
    [filesystem.file.test]
        folder = "tmp/testdata"
    [filesystem.file.test2]
        folder = "tmp/testdata2"
[filesystem.s3]
    [filesystem.s3.test]
        folder = "s3folder/testdata"
```

My go code:

```
package main

type File struct {
    Folder string `toml:"folder"`
}

type FileSystem struct {
    File map[string]File `toml:"file"`
}

type Config struct {
    FileSystem  map[string]FileSystem `toml:"filesystem"`
}

func main() {
    var conf Config
    _, err := toml.DecodeFile("test.toml", &conf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Error on loading config: ", err)
    }
    log.Printf("config: %v", conf)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TOML defined in the input corresponds to a top level `filesystem` struct, containing multiple types i.e. `file`, `s3` etc. So the right way to define the equivalent Go structs to decode those would be to do

```golang
type File struct {
    Folder string `toml:"folder"`
}

type FileSystem struct {
    File map[string]File `toml:"file"`
    S3   map[string]File `toml:"s3"`
}

type Config struct {
    FileSystem FileSystem `toml:"filesystem"`
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/lfFKVL4_1zx